# dunno what i do, splitting number like lul

Tags: python

the desired output
[splitnumber(-9)----->-5,-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVng2.png)

my code

```
def spliiiiit(angka):
    hasil1 = angka/2
    hasil1 = int(hasil1)
    batas = angka%2
    hasil2 = 0
    if batas == 0:
        hasil2 = hasil1
    elif angka < 0:
        hasil1 = hasil1 - 1
        hasil2 = hasil1 + 1
    else:
        hasil2 = (angka/2)+0.5
    hasilakhir = []
    hasilakhir.insert(0,hasil1)
    hasilakhir.insert(1, int(hasil2))
    print(hasilakhir)
```

can some one tell me how the right way to solve that
the function output is like this
*splitnumber(-9) ----> [-5,-4] or splitnumber(9) ----> [4,5]*

Comment: Please replace the images with formatted code/text. Please explain what you are trying to do. See also: [ask] and [How to format code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621)

Comment: thanks for spending times for such a questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def spliiiiit(angka):
    x = angka//2
    return(x, angka-x)
```

Comment: solved it is more simple and more effective